# Android Studio Conflicting Classes when using Library

Tags: android-studio, gradle, conflict, nineoldandroids

I have just started using Android Studio, 
So forgive me if i am unable to explain the situation properly.
But i will try to update details as required.

In my gradle project i use JakeWarton DiskCache with nineoldandroids
Both as jar files added to the app/libs folder.

In addition there also a Library project from this location 
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/122

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent:datetimepicker:0f5d399995'
}
```

I use it by adding the repository and dependency as shown above.

When i try to run this project i get following error

Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener.class

I can understand that since my app has a copy of nineoldandroids.jar and the lib-project also  needs it at compile time there is some kind of issue.

How can i fix this conflict?

Comment: You can remove the nineoldandroids.jar and use
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti Your solution worked perfectly. Sorry i coud not reply sooner.  But i have to ask , what if there are two external libraries using a common dependency jar file packaged as part of their source.

Comment: You can use the same jar (same version) in different modules. The problem here is that your library has a maven dependency with nineoldandroids while you have a jar file with the same lib. If it is ok, I will report it as an answer to help other users.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti Ok by me, you can report it as an answer. It did solve my issue, thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library `com.github.flavienlaurent:datetimepicker:0f5d399995` is using the 
`nineoldandroids` library as a maven dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    //...
}
```

[Check the origina](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker/blob/master/datetimepicker-library/build.gradle)l build.gradle file in github.

To solve your issue you have to:

- remove the nineoldandroids.jar from your project
- add the `nineoldandroids` library as maven dependency in your project

Use:

```
dependencies{
 //
 compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```